# Unknown column in on clause

Tags: mysql

I want to join 3 tables. I don't understand why I get this error:

> **ERROR 1054 (42S22):**
>
> Unknown column '`orders_items.item_id`' in 'on clause'

Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders_items
JOIN card_items ON orders_items.item_id = card_items.item_id
JOIN orders_requests ON orders_items.request_id = orders_requests.request_id
```

Comment: Show your data structure please.

Comment: Because you don't have `item_id` in `orders_items` table? Just a guess, lol

Comment: Sorry for being so inaccurate. I have an item_id in orders_item table, that's why I don't understand this error.
What's the best way to show my data structure?

Answer (score 1):

There is no column item_id in the table orders_items. Probably you've mistyped.